# FreeRTOS stuck in osDelay

Tags: embedded, stm32, freertos, rtos, cmsis

I'm working on a project using a STM32F446 with a boilerplate created with STM32CubeMX (for peripherals initialization and middleware like the FreeRTOS with the CMSIS-V1 interface).
I have two threads which communicate using mailboxes but I encountered a problem: one of the thread body is

```
void StartDispatcherTask(void const * argument)
{
    mailCommand *commandData = NULL;
    mailCommandResponse *commandResponse = NULL;
    osEvent event;
    for(;;)
    {       
        event = osMailGet(commandMailHandle, osWaitForever);
        commandData = (mailCommand *)event.value.p;

        // Here is the problem
        osDelay(5000);
    }
}
```

It gets to the delay but never gets out. Is there a problem with using the mailbox and the delay in the same thread? I tried also bringing the delay before the `for(;;)` and it works.

EDIT: I guess I can try to add more detail to the problem. The first thread send a mail of a certain type and then waits for a mail of another type; the thread in which I get the problem receive the mail go the first type and execute some code based on what it receive and then send the result as a mail of the second type; sometimes it is that it has to wait using osDelay and there it stop working but without going into any fault handler

Comment: More likely that the delay is completing and it enters `osMailGet()` where it waits forever (or at least until something sends a message or it).

Comment: Yeah I meant that the mail is get correctly, then it get to the delay but never gets to the osMailGet again

Comment: My point was rather how have you determined that for sure?  You code does nothing externally observable in that loop, so you would have to have used a debugger and break-points to determine that - which you have not mentioned.  Externally it will always appear "blocked" apart from the tiny period that it assigns `commandData` (and does nothing with it).

Comment: Yeah I actually am debugging using Keil v5; I set a breakpoint on the `osDelay` and it get reached but if I let it run again I can see that it is stuck in the `prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination` function

Comment: The code described in the "edit" does not sound like the same code.  Have you verified that the code shown in the question fails in the same manner as the code with "_execute some code based on what it receive_" in it? Is SYSTICK running?  Is the SYSTICK interrupt handler being executed?  The bit about `prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination` should appear in the question - it is probably _relevant_.  Deleting tasks should be considered "unusual" in a real-time system - the code shown does not show where or why you might be doing that.

Comment: Note also that if a higher-priority task is not blocking, the task in delay will not be scheduled after the delay expires.  Put a break-point in the idle task loop; if your system is not entering the idle loop regularly you have inappropriate task behaviour and priorities.  Every thread should be guaranteed to block, and generally the tasks that have the longest or least deterministic run-times should be assigned lower priority that shorter and more deterministic ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use standard freeRTOS API. ARM CMSIS wrapper is rubbish.

BTW I rather suspect `osMailGet(commandMailHandle, osWaitForever);`

the delay is in this case not needed at all. If you wait for the data in the BLOCKED state the task does not consume any processing power

If another guesses are:

1. You are landing in the HF
2. You are stacked in the context switch (wrong interrupt priorities )

use your debugger and see what is going on.

Comment: The first line of this is an opinion that might better be posted as a comment since it is not part of the answer.  Possibly it being "rubbish" is why there is a v2 API, but freeRTOS is no better, and subjectively worse (IMO).

Comment: I added more detail to the question, as how the delay is called in the code I showed is just a simplified example; the mail is received correctly, the problem is that I never get to `osMailGet` again

Comment: @ArenaLor connect the debugger and see where it is has stuck. Probably on the context switch as I wrote.

Comment: But _opinion_ nontheless, and has no place in the answer (just as matters of opinion have no place in questions on SO).  There are reasons one might _need_ to use it (portability of code for example)

Comment: So, apart from the fact the there shouldn't be opinion based answer, for me it is not complete rubbish because I could kickstart a project without an in-depth knowledge of the freeRTOS API and as @Clifford said, portability of code (I could switch to Keil RTX in any moment, for example)

Comment: @P__J__ , I tried also connecting with the debugger; I can see the it reaches the `osDelay` call but then it is stuck in the `prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination` function

Comment: @ArenaLor :  P__J__ has a point about the delay however, it is a poor design; if the sending task posts messages faster than 5000 tick intervals, the queue will fill and the sender will block.  Normally messages should be processed in "real-time", and you should "trust" the scheduler rather then second-guess it.  You should at least loop to process all queued messages before entering the delay if that is needed at all.

Comment: @Clifford the problem is rather tricky for the beginners correct IRQ priority settings. And I am almost sure it has stack in the SV call.

Comment: So it seems to be solved by increasing the amount of stack allocate for the two thread (from 128 bytes to 512 bytes for each). Are there any principles to choose how much stack to allocate for each thread?

Comment: @ArenaLor no - you need to analyze yourself how much stack you need

Comment: "Are there any principles to choose how much stack to allocate for each thread?" @ArenaLor, yes, make your best guess, then let your code run and call `uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark()` real-time to see how much you are actually using. You can also create a function to use as the `vApplicationStackOverflowHook()` (callback) to check for stack overflow. See 1) "how big should the stack be?" https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html#StackSize, 2) https://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html, 3)https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark.html

Comment: @ArenaLor, from the bottom of my link 1 above: "In addition, the stack usages of all the RTOS tasks can be viewed at once using the `uxTaskGetSystemState()` API function" (see https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetSystemState.html), and they also recommend reading this blog post: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/08/21/gnu-static-stack-usage-analysis/

Comment: Thank you @GabrielStaples, they're useful links!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to upvote any questions or answers you find useful on stack overflow, as well as comments. There's a little up arrow next to comments youd like to upvote. It helps them stick out so others will see them too. I just upvoted your thank you, for instance.

Comment: @Clifford - I transferred your suggestion about the sender issue to an answer.

Comment: ArenaLor - You **must** ensure that no task is exceeding its allocated stack. Otherwise, the entire discussion is pointless because the RTOS will most likely fail to maintain its properties then. Beside the (useful) run-time measurement mentioned by @GabrielStaples, many toolchains (including some free-of-charge ones like atollic) provide a static (off-line) evaluation feature for stack usage of function call graphs.

Comment: @P__J__ - I don't agree on the disqualification of the OSAL provided by ARM CMSIS in general. As ArenaLor pointed out correctly, it may simplify the kickstart. And, more important from my point of view, you maintain portability to other OSes.

Answer (score 0):

osStatus osDelay (uint32_t millisec)

The millisec value specifies the number of timer ticks.

The exact time delay depends on the actual time elapsed since the last timer tick.

For a value of 1, the system waits until the **next timer tick occurs**.

=> You have to check whether timer tick is running or not.

check this [link](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Wait.html#ga6c97d38879ae86491628f6e647639bad)

Answer (score 0):

As P__J__ pointed out in an earlier answer, you shouldn't use the `osDelay()` call in the loop<sup>1</sup>
because your task loop will wait at the `osMailGet()` call for the next request/mail until it arrives anyhow.
But this hint called my attention to another possible reason for your observation, so I'm opening this new answer:<sup>2</sup>

As the loop execution is interrupted by a delay of 5000 ticks - could it be that **the producer** of the mails is filling the mailbox faster than the task is consuming mails? Then, you should inspect if this situation is detected/handled in the producer context.

If the producer ignores "queue full" return values and discards the mails before they have been transmitted, the system will only process a few mails every 5000 ticks (or it may lose all but a few mails after the first fill of the mailbox, if the producer in your example only fills the mailbox queue once).
This could look like the consumer task being stuck, even if the main problem is about the producer context (task/ISR).

---

<sup>1</sup>
The `osDelay()` call can only help you if you want to avoid to process another mail within 5000 ticks if request mails are produced faster than the task processes them.
But then, you'd have a different problem, and you should open a different question...

<sup>2</sup>
**Edit:** I just noticed that Clifford already mentioned this option in one of his comments to the question. I think this option must be covered by an answer.